# Splitting a character column into multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, strsplit

```
y <- data.frame(x = c("63,98,131","75,109,145","66,104,139"))
```

I want to make three columns A,B,C from x by splitting from comma

```
 A  B   C
 63 98  131
 75 109 145
 66 104 139
```

I tried to use str_split

```
str_split(y$x, " , ")

[[1]]
 [1] "63,98,131"

 [[2]]
 [1] "75,109,145"

  [[3]]
  [1] "66,104,139"
```

But this does not do the job. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can use `tidyr::separate`.

Comment: This has been covered many, many times here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042621/how-to-split-column-into-two-in-r-using-separate - and the various duplicates that each of these questions link to.

Comment: You need to do `","` not `" , "`

Answer (score 0):

```
> dt=as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(y$x,",")),ncol=dim(y)[1],byrow = T))
> dt
  V1  V2  V3
1 63  98 131
2 75 109 145
3 66 104 139
```

Comment: When I run in my machine, it gives me an error `Error in strsplit(y$x, ",") : non-character argument`

Comment: Okay. I think I have sorted it out. Thank you

Comment: That's because when you created `y` it should have `stringsAsFactors=F` as an argument inside `data.frame()`. You could either fix that, or change to `as.character(y$x)`.