# Sorting Multiple Data Tables Based On Character Type Column With Sanity Check

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have two data table and want to sort them such that row value of first table is same as row value of second table based on a column named `Parameter`.

Using `order()`, the problem is that it will only sort based on the data table input. But to ensure that not only both data tables are sorted based on `Parameter` column, but are also sorted correctly by comparing the column `Parameter` row by row between two data tables as a sanity check.

Please share any faster way to do this.

**First Table Input**

```
Parameter   Data
R-1          1
R-2          1
R-3          1
P-11         1
P-12         1
P-8          2
P-9          1
P-10         1
R-4          1
R-5          1
P-14         1
P-15         1
```

**Second Table Input**

```
Parameter   Data
R-1          2
P-9          2
R-3          2
P-11         2
P-12         2
P-8          2
R-2          2
P-10         2
R-4          2
R-5          3
P-14         2
P-15         2
```

**Desired Outputs**

**First Table Output**

```
Parameter   Data
R-1         1
R-2         1
R-3         1
R-4         1
R-5         1
P-8         2
P-9         1
P-10        1
P-11        1
P-12        1
P-14        1
P-15        1
```

**Second Table Output**

```
Parameter   Data
R-1         2
R-2         2
R-3         2
R-4         2
R-5         3
P-8         2
P-9         2
P-10        2
P-11        2
P-12        2
P-14        2
P-15        2
```

Comment: It almost sounds like you might want to use some dplyr join option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr::separate`.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

# Function to split up parameter into two pieces and sort like example
sort_table <- function(df) {
  df %>%  separate(Parameter, c("letter", "num"), remove = F) %>%
  arrange(desc(letter), as.numeric(num))
}

# Join the two sorted tables
full_join(
  sort_table(table_1),
  sort_table(table_2),
  by = c("Parameter", "letter", "num")
)



#   Parameter letter num Data.x Data.y
#1        R-1      R   1      1      2
#2        R-2      R   2      1      2
#3        R-3      R   3      1      2
#4        R-4      R   4      1      2
#5        R-5      R   5      1      3
#6        P-8      P   8      2      2
#7        P-9      P   9      1      2
#8       P-10      P  10      1      2
#9       P-11      P  11      1      2
#10      P-12      P  12      1      2
#11      P-14      P  14      1      2
#12      P-15      P  15      1      2
```

Comment: .@JonSpring - Before I saw your answer today, yesterday I implemented similar approach using `separate()`. I think there is no other way than splitting and then sorting based on numeric and letters.

Comment: .@JonSpring - Is it possible to do this with base `R` package?

Comment: I bet there's a way with `strsplit` and `merge`, but I don't know the syntax as well.

Comment: .@JonSpring - Thank you. I did it with `strsplit()`. Had to covert `list()` output to `data.frame()`. It worked.