# How to crate a network from a string vector

Tags: r, for-loop, networking, dplyr, igraph

I am trying to create an `igraph` object splitting a string vector on a special character ("&").
I use a for-loop to create a vector and convert that into a network graph.
The code works but is extremely inefficient on very long vectors (large networks).

Is there a way to improve the process with pipes and mapping?
Thanks in advance

```
require(graph)
data <- data.frame(nodes=c("A","A & B","C","B & C","B & D"))

V <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  V_temp <- data[i,]
  ifelse(grepl(" & ", data$nodes[i]),
         N <- t(combn(unlist(strsplit(data$nodes[i], " & ")),2)),
         N <- matrix(rep(data$nodes[i],2), nrow = 1, ncol = 2))
  colnames(N) <- c("N1","N2")
  V_temp <- cbind(N, V_temp, row.names = NULL)
  V <- as.data.frame(rbind(V, V_temp, row.names = NULL))
}

vector <- rbind(as.vector(as.character(V$N1)),
                as.vector(as.character(V$N2)))
plot(graph(vector, directed = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data %>%
      separate(nodes, c("from", "to") ) %>%
      mutate(to = coalesce(to,from))

  from to
1    A  A
2    A  B
3    C  C
4    B  C
5    B  D

Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [1, 3]. 

g <- graph_from_data_frame(d)
```

`separate` returns a warning, telling you sometimes there is nothing to split. In the second step you fill in the `NA` in the column "to" with values from column "from".

You could also specify the split if you want `separate(nodes, c("from", "to"), " & " )`.

[Split data frame string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-data-frame-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

[How to split column into two in R using separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042621/how-to-split-column-into-two-in-r-using-separate)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the two suggestions from **desval** I came up with this.
This works for when separate operate on one or two nodes, fails with higher numbers. For example for `data <- data.frame(nodes=c("E","A & B","C","B & C","B & D & E"))`

Se below updated code

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

selfloop <- function(x){
  y <- ifelse(!grepl(" & ",x), paste(x,x, sep = " & "), x)
  return(y)
}

data <- data.frame(nodes=c("E","A & B","C","B & C","B & D"))


g <- data %>%
  mutate(nodes = selfloop(nodes)) %>%
  separate(nodes, c("from", "to"), sep = " & ") %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE)

plot(g)
```

Comment: do you need to have a vector? It is much easier to pass in a data frame with from and to columns to igraph. This allows you to keep the code clean and easy to read. Also, it will be faster, I guess.